# Re-calculating Value of $100 in Each State by Specific State

Tags: relations, correlation

I'm using this [Tax Foundations graphic](http://taxfoundation.org/sites/taxfoundation.org/files/docs/Price-Parity-2012.png) for data.

How would I re-calculate each state based on a specific state?  For example, what if I wanted to base the control state on Missouri, which is $113.51.  What's the best equation to use to re-calculate other states so they're still relative to Missouri?

Would multiplying state * new state do it?  i.e. if Missouri s $113.51, I would multiply each state by 1.1351?  Or am I way off here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, then you want to calculate how much sb can buy in a state relative more/less  to Missouri (in percent).

The term equation would be $\left( \frac{X}{113.51}-1\right) \cdot 100 \% $. Thus you divide by 113.51.

Comment: Good deal, that looks like a winner based on a few calculations I just did.  I was close, just needed to divide instead of multiply, heh. Thanks